# Python: How to edit (global) variable in multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot that will play musics. Currently I'm trying to make queue work.
This is the code I have:

```py
...
    songList = []

    PATH = "./happy/"
    files = os.listdir(PATH)

    def AddToList(f):
        songList.append(f)

    for f in files:
        AddToList(f)


        song_num = 0
        songPath = PATH + songList[song_num]

    def SongDone(self):
            print("------\nSongDone was passed\n-------")
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(songPath), after = playSong) 
            voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source) 
            voice.source.volume = 0.07
            print(f"playing song {songPath}")
            global song_num
            song_num += 1
            print(f"Song number: {song_num}")
```

What I'm trying to do is make two functions, which will pass eachother after the song ends.
Discord.py has `after` in `voice.play`, which does what it says after the song end. This would create a loop and each time they are passed they will edit `song_num`, this would change the song which will be played path from file in position 0 to position 1 then 2 and so on. When I use `print(f"Song number: {song_num}")` to check if it actually works, it adds 1 everytime the functions pass eachother (the first time it jumps from 1 to 3 and I'm not sure why). What I don't get about this its that it `song_num` is edited, but songPath doesn't change and therefore the same song (the one in position 0) is played over and over again. I think the problem is `song_num` variable but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to declare a variable `songPath` in the body of the program and not inside any loop or function. Then make it global and run the code and see if the path gets modified. Do ask for further queries.

Comment: hey @Jyotirmay Kumar Jha , apperantly I'm dumb and declared `song_num` outside the whole command, which was set to 2, thats the reason I was getting a 3 the second time the loop was executed. I moved the code which creates the list and `songPath` outside of the command itself The code still doesn't work for some reason. [Here's the code.](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2Wz) (only the part that its in our interest to fix what's wrong). I would use debugger to track down the variables but unfortunately I haven't learned how to use it yet. Thanks for taking your time to help me.